# Is there way to setup approval for azure ad b2c user creation?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

We want to use Azure AD B2C to use clien/contractors to create and use their account but all accounts has to be validated due to some regulations requirements.

So once user create account we want to make sure it is valid account before user can access application with newly created account

Comment: Same here, how did you implement this?

Comment: @jackomo - Just create a custom attribute called AccountVerified and set it to False by default. Use this flag to determine whether or not the validation has been completed. Once you've verified the account, update the AccountVerified claim to True using the Graph API.

If you know a better way, let me know!

Answer (score 3):

In your policy configuration, you can select the "User is new" claim type in the Application claims section. The first time user access to your application, the claim will appear in the id_token and you can handle it to do custom process with the user. This is the only reference i found about this claim: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies

Comment: how can we perform the custom custom process with the user?